# Adding to cart when I go back and forth on the site

Tags: php, html, refresh, cart

I have this "add to cart" link that sends getdata and adding +1 when it's submitted/isset.

The problem is that when I refresh the page, and when I go back and forth, it will add again because the data is still there in the url. How can I prevent this? Im open to different solutions.

I did find something about PRG method. This method uses a redirect. But if I redirect won't it still add if I go back and forth?

Take care

Comment: "Add to cart" should generally be a POST, not a GET.

Comment: Allright mate. But I will still have the same problem even if I change the method :)

Comment: POST parameters aren't passed on the URL and don't survive redirects.

Comment: I am still checking if the GET isset, and if isset I will ++. So if I change everything to POST, same thing should happen on refresh?

Comment: No, that's the point of PRG. The form submission is a POST, you process the form, then redirect to a GET. The POST parameters are now lost, and if the user clicks refresh, they're refreshing the GET page with no parameters, not the POST page.

Comment: Allright. I'll play around with this and get back to you later

Comment: So the redirect method solved the problem, and it works fine with both get and post method. I can now refresh and go back and forth without any unwanted additions.

Answer (score 0):

Make "add to cart" into a pseudo-link, which appears as a link, but when clicked it handles it differently. For example in jQuery:

```
$('.add-to-card').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post({
        id: put the product id here,
    }).then(function () {
        increase the counter in the button
    })
});
```

This way your link will not make it into the browser history and traversing it (using back and forward buttons in the browser) will not affect your cart's state.